# Evaluating in buffer different from evaluating in slime?

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, slime

I am using emacs to learn how to program in common lisp, and I have bumped up against a confusing issue. When I enter the expression

```
(defconstant +some-constant+ (make-hash-table))
```

and I evaluate it with

```
M-x eval-buffer
```

I get the error

```
Symbol's function definition is void: defconstant
```

But if I copy and paste this into the slime repl, it works perfectly. Of course, this renders most of the handy keyboard shortcuts for evaluating lisp code within your program without having to execute the entire program. I end up copying everything out of my buffer into the slime terminal whenever I want to test something.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`M-x eval-buffer` will evaluate the buffer as emacs lisp, not as Common Lisp. You probably want `C-c C-k`, which will compile and load the file.

In general, if you see a lisp-related command without a prefix of `slime-` it is probably an emacs-lisp facility.

Comment: When I use C-c C-k, it compiles, but when I try to execute any functions I defined in the file via slime repl, it complains that the function is undefined?

Comment: Hmm. That's not what should happen, and is isn't the behaviour I'm getting. Make sure that the file loads in your lisp OK (by loading it in a standalone session outside of emacs).

Comment: @mooglinux also, if you're putting your code in separate package (using cl:in-package on top of your buffer/file) make sure that you switched the package in the REPL (using the same cl:in-package).